# Punctuation rules in a business letter addressed to several recipients

Tags: punctuation, greetings

I usually use:

> Diana,
>
> Thank you for..
>
> Dan,
>
> I considered your..

I've seen in my incoming letters:

> Diana - thank you..
>
> Dan - I considered your..

So the questions is:
What is the right way to write a letter addressed to several recipients?

Comment: There is no *right* way—unless you are following a specific style guide. Dashes are new to me (I normally see a comma or a colon), but there's nothing preventing them from being used.

Comment: Is this a letter, or an email?  It is normal to send an email to multiple people, but not a paper letter.

Comment: I see no evidence of several recipients in your example. It depends on the formality or informality of the letter. And how many recipients exactly do you mean??

Answer (score 1):

What your example is showing is a standard way of sending an email to multiple recipients where more than one needs to be specifically communicated to.  There is no "***right***" way to do this as long as each person's section is clearly delineated.